# running jupyterlab as ubuntu 20.04 service permissions issue

Tags: ubuntu, service, jupyter-lab

Im running a jupyterlab server on aws. All is well when I run the server from a working folder (just type 'jupyter lab' in the the folder to serve from...) all of the kernels I have install are loaded and working.
The issue arises when I try and set up a service. Here is my service:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/jupyterlab.service
[Unit]
Description=Jupyterlab
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
WorkignDirectory=/home/ubuntu
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/jupyterlab.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script is just as simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
jupyter-lab --port=8888 --no-browser
```

The issues is that that this service will not load some of my kernels. I have changed the permissions in the anaconda folder every which way. I have added an export to the path in the script for the anaconda3/bin and others. Still the system will not load the kernel when using service.
I also moved the service to the `~/.config/systemd/user/jupyterlab.service`. Still no luck.

Any tips or workarounds will be appreciated.... regards.

Answer (score 0):

Alright.... I solved this by just installing everything as the default user... `ubuntu`. I was originally placing the conda installation in the `/opt` folder.

I also created the service as a user service so that its not run as root. Here is an example --> https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-systemd-service-without-root-sudo/

Still something wrong with my permission as I would like manage this for multiple users but for now its working and I can move on... for a bit. Also now the service loads dead???? need to work this too.